# Path of Python is trying to access an old version. And this path is not accessible in the Finder (in MacOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, path, installation

I installed Python 3.7 on my mac. I had previously version 3.6 as well as Anaconda which I tried to uninstall. When I call `python3` from Terminal it works. And after entering the following line: `sys.path`

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

I can successfully open an jupyter notebook. However, when I tried to run the code on the Jupyter notebook, it seems that the jupyter is trying to look in the path of python 3.6 I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1543, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 148, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7'
```

**Edit 1**

From my bash profile (command `nano ~/.bash_profile`), I get the following output:

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/mymac/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/Applications/Python/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/Applications/Python/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/mymac/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 5.0.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 5.1.0 installer
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Virtualenv/VirtualenvWrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

**Edit 2**

I deleted almost everything from my `bash profile` and have now only this output from:

```
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

The error message in `jupyter` changed a bit in the sense that it tries to look for the bin in python 3.7 instead of 3.6 but it still doesn't work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 736, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 729, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 736, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 729, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 736, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 729, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 160, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7'
```

Those errors appear although I changed the path the `.json` file in `/Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json`. There I changed the path to `There I changed the path to`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7`

Comment: what does the output of `which jupyter` return

Comment: thank you for your comment @aws_apprentice. this is the output: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter`

Comment: Those errors appear althouth I changed the path the `.json` file in `/Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json`. There I changed the path to `There I changed the path to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7`

Comment: how about the PATH in your bash profile

Comment: @aws_apprentice. I'm afraid that goes beyond my knowledge of the Terminal: Which exact command do I have to enter to get the PATH in my bash profile?

Comment: echo $PATH is the command

Comment: thank you for your comment @aws_apprentice. I edited the question and added the output of the command `nano ~/.bash_profile` in the Terminal

Comment: so you need to add 3.7 to your profile and remove 3.6 and older from your path

Comment: Many thanks @aws_apprentice. So I removed almost everything from the bash profile (all the anaconda path as well as python 3.6). Python 3.7 was already there so I just didn't delete it. The error message from jupyter changed: it seems that it tries to look for bin in python 3.7 instead of 3.6. so that's an improvement but there it is still not working. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: As an aside, there is certainly no need to `export` the same variable multiple times. Your system's Bash startup files probably already `export PATH` on your behalf so you should not even need to do it once yourself.